# correct way to invoke a function in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I just recently started to learn OCaml, and I have a small issue

I'm trying to generate a series of numbers with the following function

```
let new_num =
  let cpt = ref (-1) in
  fun () -> incr cpt; Printf.sprintf "__number_%i" !cpt
```

When I run `ocaml` in a terminal I can get a number with something like:
`let n = new_num()`

But when I add the above function to an existing file (that works, just provided to me) and try to call it like this, I get an error on the line containing with the call to the `new_num` function

```
let matching_function i = match i with
  | case1 -> ... (* a code that works fine*)

  | C(e,s1,s2)->
    let n1 = new_num() in
    n1
    let n2 = new_num() in
    n2
    let code_e = trl e in  (* trl is a working function somewhere else in my code)
    code_e
    (* rest of code and print n1,n2*)
```

if I remove the following part and run the file everything works perfectly.

```
let n1 = new_num() in
n1
let n2 = new_num() in
n2
```

I don't understand why this works in terminal interpreter but not when I run it in a .ml file? Can someone please explain it to me and help call it correctly? (sorry for the novice question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the file is not syntactically valid, that's all that's going on.

You can't have this:

```
let n1 = new_num () in n1
let ...
```

The second `let` isn't syntactically valid at that point.

You almost certainly want something like this:

```
let n1 = new_num () in
let n2 = new_num () in
...
```

This defines `n1` and `n2` for later use in the code.

The reason it works in the interpreter is that you're not typing in this same code.

Here's what you actually see if you type the erroneous lines into the toplevel (the interpreter):

```
# let n1 = new_num () in n1
  let n2 = new_num () in n2;;
Error: Syntax error
```

If you add `;;` between the two lines it is accepted (though it doesn't actually define top-level values named `n1` and `n2`). But this isn't the same code. The `;;` has a syntactic effect.

As a side comment, this expression:

```
let n1 = new_num () in n1
```

is exactly equivalent to this expression:

```
new_num ()
```

In particular, it doesn't define a value `n1` that you can use later. The scope of the definition of `v` in `let v = e1 in e2` is just `e2`.